# how to show multi level tables in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm new in mvc . i have this diagram [part of my data base diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K03w4.jpg)

I want to show to `orders user` , `status order` and `products order`.and i test many ways but not successful.
in view model:

```
public class OrderListViewModel
{
  public  List<Order> orders { get; set; }

}
```

controller:

```
        BOL.User CurrentUser = _user.user.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        int UserId = CurrentUser.ID;
        var listorders =  _order.UserOrders(UserId) ;
        List<OrderListViewModel> orderVM = new List<OrderListViewModel>();
            orderVM.Add (new OrderListViewModel { orders=listorders.ToList()
            }
            );
        return View(orderVM);
```

in view:

```
    @model  IEnumerable<OrderListViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

  Html.Display(item.orders.Select(x=>x.Status.StatusName).FirstOrDefault());
    foreach (var fact in item.orders.ToList())
    {
        Html.Display(fact.Factors.);
    }
    <br />
    Html.Display("****");
}
```

and i don't know how to show products in each order??

Comment: Perhaps include some of the error messages and/or issues that you're encountering?

Comment: The first thing that I notice is regarding `orderVM` - why are you creating a `List<OrderListViewModel>()` instead of simply `var orderVM = new OrderListViewModel()`?

Comment: @sleeyuen when i do this ,get error for filled the object :var orderVM = new OrderListViewModel();
            orderVM.orders.Add(new Order { Factors=listorders.Select(x=>x.Factors).ToList() });

Comment: Try adding this to your model: `public OrderListViewModel() { order = new List<Order>(); }` - this should enable you to use `.Add` immediately after creating orderVM.

Comment: also in controller when i set status get error: orderVM.orders.Add(new Order { Factors = listfactors  , Status=listorders.Select(x=>x.Status.StatusName).FirstOrDefault()});

Comment: Help me to help you here...what are the error(s)? Can you display something simpler, like a string property directly on `orders`? If you breakpoint the `return View` line, does `orderVM` contain the nested objects that you're expecting?  It's too vague now what the issue is.